How to draw multiples mappolylines
I am trying to add several distinct lines on QML map embeded in widgets application.
I plot markers on the MAP with a MapQuickItem from a JSON and in this JSON there are some lineString that I would like to add too but they are linked to each other
This is my attempt:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtPositioning
import QtLocation
import QtCore
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
            id: map
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: mapPlugin
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.441706425544,19.50356807068)
            zoomLevel: 5

            property geoCoordinate startCentroid

            WheelHandler {    // zoom molette
                id: wheel
                rotationScale: 1/100
                property: "zoomLevel"
            }
            DragHandler {
                id: drag
                target: null
                onTranslationChanged: (delta) => map.pan(-delta.x, -delta.y)
            }

            MapCircle {
                id:cl
                center: lignes
                radius: 20000
                color: 'black'
            }
            MapItemView
            {
                model: pl
                MapPolyline{
                        id:pl
                        line.color: "blue"
                        width: 2
                        visible: true
                        path: pl

                }
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                var JsonString = '{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[19.50356807068,59.441706425544],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"color":"Red","name":"Svenska Högarna"},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[18.474967922139,57.474603476726],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"color":"Red","name":"Gotland Island"},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[23.958410829456,61.156042630065],[23.040209031792,61.150377804625]],"type":"LineString"},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[24.958410829456,60.156042630065],[25.040209031792,60.150377804625]],"type":"LineString"},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[24.958410829456,60.156042630065],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"color":"Red","name":""},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[25.040209031792,60.150377804625],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"color":"Green","name":""},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[24.9945,60.1518],[23.1585,59.1111],[21.1988,59.5741],[20.0335,59.8579],[19.4794,59.4686],[18.1034,58.4287],[17.89,57.3109],[17.789,56.5184],[18.6508,56.8946],[20.2978,57.6451],[21.3818,58.618],[21.9284,59.0893],[22.9255,59.2777],[24.2345,59.5249],[24.9983,60.1533]],"type":"LineString"},"properties":{"color":"white"},"type":"Feature"}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}'
                var data = JSON.parse(JsonString);
                var list = data["features"];
                var path = []
                for (var i in list)
                {
                    if (list[i]["geometry"]["type"]==="LineString")
                    {

                        for(var j in list[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"])
                        {
                            path.push(
                                        {
                                            latitude:list[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"][j][1],
                                            longitude:list[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"][j][0]
                                        })
                        }
                        pl.path = path
                        console.log(path[0].latitude)

                    }

                }

            }

        }
}

How can I solve the problem?

Is this answer of help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77570081/881441
